# How to give linearlayout Context

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-context

I have a problem with my current project in android studio.
I am trying to write some code, which creates new TextViews and ImageViews for a new activity.
This code and the new activity should start if a button is clicked.

To add the new Viewers, I try to access the existing LinearLayout in the xml-file of the new activity. But it always says that I try to *"invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference"*

So my question is how can I give the Linear Layout some context?

Here is my onClick-method. The parseXML()-method creates the new Viewers by parsing an XML-file.

```
 public void onClick(View view) {
    linearLayout= findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutArtikel);

    parseXML();
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, ArtikelActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for your suggestions, moving the code to the new Activity solved the problem!

Comment: Move `linearLayout= findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutArtikel);` to your onCreate() method?

Comment: You can't do it in the first Activity. Move this part in the `ArtikelActivity` in the `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout is part of ArtikelActivity if you are trying to access it from anyother activity then you will get that message. So move your code to ArtikelActivity. This is gonna work surely.